# Are these called "good cart" and "serving cart"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Is this called a **good cart**" which is used to carry heavy things and often used in construction?

[image]

Is this called a "**food cart**" which is used to carry and sell food on streets? It might have 3 wheels (2 big and one small) or 4 small wheels.

[image]

or

[image]

Some looks like **a bike with a cart on the front** and the seller can move the cart by cycling instead of pushing like this.

[image]

Comment: Not "good cart"; **goods** cart, if you must.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more than one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will probably depend very much on the specific dialect of English.  There may also be "specialist terms" used in industry that will be different from what the general population would use.

**Good cart** or **goods cart** is unusual in American English and might not be understood.  We would probably call the first picture a **dolly**, a **handtruck** (or **hand truck**) or a **platform truck**.

A **food cart** is any kind of non-motorized cart that is used to sell food from.  I don't think we have a special name for the kind that is like a bicycle.

**Trolley**, in American English, can be used to mean something like your first picture, but usually means something like a streetcar or tram.

References:

- [Uline, "Material Handling"](https://www.uline.com/Cls_07/Material-Handling)
- [WebstaurantStore, "Dollies and Hand Trucks"](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/24769/trucks-and-dollies.html)
- [Grainger, "Transporting"](https://www.grainger.com/category/material-handling/transporting)

Comment: good cart does not exist in American English. It would have to be goods with an s, otherwise you get good cart/bad cart. Basic grammar.

Answer (score 2):

**Goods** cart, or trolley.
The singular 'good' does exist, but it is almost never used in practical terms.

The rest to me would be variations on the theme of 'food stall'. Describing it as a food stall doesn't make any claim as to how or if it ever moves. It perhaps conveys an idea of at best 'semi-permanence' - it's made of steel or wood with a simple roof - not brick & stone with slates.
You might go so far as to call it a 'mobile food stall' to differentiate from one in a fixed position. If you wanted to describe how it is actually moved, tackle that as a separate issue.

This is a typical English market stall. It may only be there one or two days a week & between times will be completely dismantled & removed, so the rest of the time there's no evidence of its existence.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

The last one of your images with half a bike might have a special name, but it's not one I'm familiar with. You don't really see them in the UK.

Comment: Although we don't typically have these in the UK, I'd probably just call it a food stand or food stall. The fact it's connected to a bike or vehicle makes little difference.  Food stands/stalls are often attached to a vehicle for towing, rather than a bike.  "food cart" sounds American, although I don't know if they'd use that TBH.

Comment: @BillyKerr - without concrete evidence, I'd go for 'stall' being UK, 'stand' being US for probably very similar things.

Comment: not sure to be honest, there's a lot of to-and-fro across the pond these days.

Comment: I'm all 'fro' these days. I have to pick up my Transpondian from the TV ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to blame it on the TV.  Sometimes I'm not even sure I live in the UK any more when you listen to some of the cr*p on TV. I'm Scottish, so I'm already a bit out of the ordinary as far as language is concerned, and we have quite a few usages that are a bit closer to US English anyway, probably because so many Scots emigrated to the US.

Comment: @BillyKerr definitely the kind of food stand attached to a bike could be called a "food cart" here in the US (NYC). Definitely would *not* be called a "food stall"

Comment: @Esther - yes "stall" in this sense is likely a UK thing, perhaps also Australia and N Zealand. Really just refers to a temporary structure for selling stuff - also a market stall, fruit and veg stall, etc.  It's a pretty common term here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably call the first a "goods trolley", though "goods cart" would probably be understandable.  Note "goods" must be plural. In context "trolley" would probably be enough.

> Can you get that red trolley, I want to take this stuff out to the van.

The second, perhaps "vending trolley" or "vending cart", and the third perhaps "vending trike".

It would be pretty rare to actually need a word - perhaps if you are setting up an online business to sell such items it would be useful. Otherwise it is just "the trolley" or "the trike", because context would make it clear.

Examples:

- [A goods trolley](https://www.cartonboxes.sg/buy-online/trolleys-and-carts/goods-trolley-73x48cm-blue)
- [Etsy page of vending carts](https://www.etsy.com/uk/market/vending_carts)
- [a cold drinks vending trike](https://www.cargobike.co.uk/product/chilled-vending-trike/)

This is how a person selling the carts might describe them.  For the customers of the food, the number and type of wheels is fairly irrelevant.  These are kebab stalls (or whatever) The type of food is far more relevant to a hungry person than the wheels.

Comment: Not to be too nit-picky, but to me 'vendor' etc is more of a correct term, but not one people would jump to first, based on the commonality of 'market stall' as a term. "There's a kebab stall on the corner" vs "There's a kebab vendor…"

Comment: I'd agree,  I don't think people would refer to the trolley or cart from which the kebabs (or whatever) are being sold.  For customers, whether it has wheels (and so is a trolley) or legs (and so is a stand) is fairly irrelevant.  Shall edit.

Comment: I think I'd call something that sold food and can be wheeled around a "food trolly" or "food cart", I'm thinking of the trolleys used in aircraft and the long gone tea trolleys that used to be a feature of our offices and factories before the introduction of vending machines.

Comment: To me [for no particular reason other than familiarity] a trolley would be an indoor device; a tea trolley that comes round an office twice a day [if they even still have such things].